# Display pop-up when the last tab is closed for domain

Tags: javascript, tabs, popup

Is it possible to display a pop-up window when the last tab of a website is closed?

For example, we have the X website. I open three pages on X, therefore I get 3 tabs opened - home, news, contact. I want that, when the last tab (doesn't matter the page/order of closing) is closed, a popup window should be displayed.

I need to display a message in a that window.

Comment: It all depends on what you mean by 'closing tabs' - the ones at your page, or the browser ones. If former, it's rather trivial (you just keep count of opened tabs, handling all the closing by decrementing this count); if latter, it depends on browser's ability to provide you with `beforeunload` or `unload` events.

Comment: As for `pop-up` effect, did you check jQuery UI [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) widget?

Comment: @raina77ow I think he's up for the later. You should post that as an answer and get the credit... Just sayin'.

Comment: What is a *tab* exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following approach to achieve this.

1. On first load of the page set up a cookie for your domain with a counter.
   **(Remember not increase the counter on page reload or F5)**
2. Then on every subsequent  new tab increase the counter of that cookie for your domain.
3. Decrease the counter on tab close by capturing the tab close event.
4. Finally on the last close capture the  tab close event and display the pop-up and clear the cookie. This will ensure that the cookie will reset once you close all the tabs.

Here is the link to [capture](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/02/22/jquery-javascript-capture-the-browser-or-tab-closed-event/) the close event.